# How do I use optimist in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, yarnpkg

Whenever I run `yarn`, I get a warning that this gem has been deprecated and that I should switch to optimist as soon as possible:

```
$ yarn
[DEPRECATION] This gem has been renamed to optimist and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist as soon as possible.
```

Because of this, I ran `gem install optimist` to install optimist, but I have no idea how to use it. If I simply try to run the command `optimist`, it doesn't do anything:

```
$ optimist

Command 'optimist' not found, did you mean:
```

How do I use optimist? Specifically, how do I use it to replace yarn, since it will no longer be supported in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem `yarn` depends on trollop which is renamed to `optimist`. The error is just a deprecation warning so everything will continue to work.

If you want to remove the error, one should update the `yarn` gem to use `optimist`. However, since the `yarn` gem is so old (2011), and there is a npm/js library called yarn which is used to install npm packages: are you sure you need to use the `yarn` gem at all?

Comment: Ruby told me that I needed to run "yarn install --check-files" and it said that --check-files was an unknown argument when I did. I don't know what's correct, I just know that I can't run my Rails app without running this command apparently.

Comment: You should remove the `yarn` gem and install `yarn` using npm instead.